# Need help understanding about unqualified ranges

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone help me understand why this works:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Inventory Data").Range("A1:G1").Copy
    Sheets("Desig From Inv").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

But, this does not?

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Inventory Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 7)).Copy
    Sheets("Desig From Inv").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

I really want the column number to be a variable in the end.  Like this:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Inventory Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, i)).Copy
    Sheets("Desig From Inv").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

I have tried many forms of getting "Cells" into the "Range".

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Sheets("Inventory Data").Range(Sheets("Inventory Data").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Inventory Data").Cells(1, i)).Copy`. Could have to do with not fully qualifying the `Cells()`.

Comment: Mat's Mug explained your issue here, but I'd also suggest this as a use case for `Resize()`  - e.g. `Sheets("Inventory Data").Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 7).Copy` since it avoids the scoping problem.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that helps.  I was suspecting something to do with qualifying, but I couldn't visualize why and how to correct it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement:

```
Sheets("Inventory Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, i)).Copy
```

Is really doing this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Data") _
              .Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i)) _
              .Copy
```

Unless `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Data")` is the `ActiveSheet`, the statement is going to blow up, because you're using a range on *another sheet* to get a range on `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory Data")`.

Qualify all the things!

...a `With` block makes this easier:

```
With Worksheets("Inventory Data")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, i)).Copy
End With
```

---

I'll allow myself a little plug here; I'm working on a (free & open-source) VBE add-in that can easily find these errors for you - paste your code [at the bottom of this page](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/List) (it runs *much* faster in the actual VBE though) to see everything Rubberduck can find in your code - it's not perfect (yet), but it's better than nothing at all:

[image: Rubberduck inspection results]

Comment: NICE ! the free encyclopedia

Answer (score 1):

some other ways:

```
    Sheets("Inventory Data").Cells(1, 1).Resize(,i).Copy
    Sheets("Desig From Inv").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

or

```
    Sheets("Inventory Data").Range("A1").Resize(,i).Copy
    Sheets("Desig From Inv").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

or

```
    Sheets("Desig From Inv").Range("A1").Resize(,i).Value = Sheets("Inventory Data").Range("A1").Resize(,i).Value
```

or

```
    With Sheets("Inventory Data").Range("A1").Resize(,i)
        Sheets("Desig From Inv").Range("A1").Resize(,i).Value = .Value
    End With
```