# Repeat even numbers in an array VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro for where a user inputs a number and the even numbers are repeated in an array. I have got the code for repeating the numbers from 0-n  (n being the number inputted). However, I don't know how to go about repeating the even numbers twice.

```
Sub Macro3()

For n = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) + 1

    Cells(2, 1 + n).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = (n - 1)
    
Next

End Sub
```

Below is the output
[Current code vs what I really want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iswj6.png)

Comment: Hi @braX I've edited in the current code vs what I want the code to do

Comment: So 0 isn't even?

Comment: @JvdV Let's say 0 is the odd one out, sorry mathematicians reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is really ok, just add question is number even and one more variable to see where to write. Also just change n loop from 0:

```
Sub Macro3()

For n = 0 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2)
    
    a = a + 1
    Cells(2, 2 + a).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = n

    'check if number is even and check if a > 1 because we don't want to repeat 0
    If n Mod 2 = 0 And a > 1 Then
        a = a + 1
        Cells(2, 2 + a).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = n
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Fine you contribute to SO :-) fyi There are some basic links helping to improve further coding: a) [How to avoid using select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) b) [Need help understanding unqualified ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864375/need-help-understanding-about-unqualified-ranges/42864517#42864517) @AleksandarJovanovic

Answer (score 1):

### Write an Array of Integers

- Writes an array of integers between 0 and the specified value in cell `B1` to a row range starting from `B2`. Even numbers are written twice (one worksheet).

**Initial Solution**

- This is a slow solution meant to be educational in understanding object variables (*workbook-worksheet-range*), ranges (`Resize`, `Offset`), loops,...

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteArrayOfIntegersRange()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Write Array of Integers Range"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Create a reference to the source cell.
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = ws.Range("B1")
    
    ' Write the value of the source cell to a variable.
    Dim sValue As Variant: sValue = sCell.Value
    
    Dim LastInteger As Long
    
    ' Validate the source cell value.
    If IsNumeric(sValue) Then ' is a number
        LastInteger = Abs(CLng(sValue)) ' positive ('Abs'), whole ('CLng')
    Else ' is not a number
        MsgBox "The value in cell '" & sCell.Address(0, 0) & "' ('" _
            & sValue & "' is not a number.", vbCritical, ProcTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create a reference to the first destination cell.
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = ws.Range("B2"): dCell.Value = 0
    
    Dim Size As Long: Size = 1
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    ' Loop through the numbers and apply alternating row size (1 or 2)
    ' and column offset (2 or 1) before writing.
    For n = 1 To LastInteger
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(, Size) ' define next first cell
        Size = 2 - n Mod 2 ' calculate the size (Odd = 1, Even = 2)
        dCell.Resize(, Size).Value = n ' write to the resized row range
    Next n
    
    ' Clear the range to the right of the last cell to remove any previous data.
    Dim crrg As Range
    With dCell.Offset(, Size) ' define next first cell
        ' Define the range from the next first to the last worksheet cell
        ' in the row.
        Set crrg = .Resize(, ws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1)
    End With
    crrg.Clear ' or crrg.ClearContents
    
    MsgBox "Array of numbers written.", vbInformation, ProcTitle

End Sub
```

**Using Arrays**

- This is a more advanced solution that utilizes the multi-purpose `GetArrayOfIntegers` function. By modifying the related constants (`Function Parameters`) in the following procedure, you can easily change the output.
- Note that it returns the results in another worksheet (`Sheet2`).
- The last procedure is created for anyone to quickly get a flavor of the `GetArrayOfIntegers` function. Just add a new workbook, add a new module and copy the codes to it. Modify the function parameters in the last procedure to get different results in the `Immediate window` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

```vb
Sub WriteArrayOfIntegers()
' Needs the 'GetArrayOfIntegers' function.
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Write Array of Numbers"
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCellAddress As String = "B1"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "B2"
    ' Function Parameters ' experiment with these five parameters
    Const EvensCount As Long = 2
    Const OddsCount As Long = 1
    Const DoReturnRow As Boolean = True
    Const IncludeZero As Boolean = True
    Const IsZeroOdd As Boolean = True
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Create a reference to the source cell.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = sws.Range(sCellAddress)
    
    ' Write the value of the source cell to a variable.
    Dim sValue As Variant: sValue = sCell.Value
    
    Dim LastInteger As Long
    
    ' Validate the source cell value.
    If IsNumeric(sValue) Then ' is a number
        LastInteger = Abs(CLng(sValue)) ' positive ('Abs'), whole ('CLng')
    Else ' is not a number
        MsgBox "The value in cell '" & sCell.Address(0, 0) & "' ('" _
            & sValue & "' is not a number.", vbCritical, ProcTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Return the result (an array) of the 'GetArrayOfIntegers' function.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetArrayOfIntegers( _
        LastInteger, EvensCount, OddsCount, DoReturnRow, IncludeZero, IsZeroOdd)
    ' Without the constants it would be:
    'Data = GetArrayOfIntegers(LastInteger, 2, 1, True, True, True)
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    ' Create a reference to the first destination cell.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dfCellAddress)
    
    ' Clear all cells next to (to the right of) and below
    ' the first destination cell.
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dfCell.Resize( _
        dws.Rows.Count - dfCell.Row + 1, dws.Columns.Count - dfCell.Column + 1)
    dcrg.Clear ' or dcrg.ClearContents
    
    ' Create a reference to the destination range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the destination range.
    drg.Value = Data
    
    MsgBox "Array of numbers written.", vbInformation, ProcTitle

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Author:       VBasic2008
' Dates:        20211101
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns an array of integers in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      The first element is always 0 or 1.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetArrayOfIntegers( _
    ByVal LastInteger As Long, _
    Optional ByVal EvensCount As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal OddsCount As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal DoReturnRow As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal IncludeZero As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal IsZeroOdd As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    
    Dim eoArr() As Long: ReDim eoArr(0 To 1)
    eoArr(0) = EvensCount: eoArr(1) = OddsCount
    
    Dim zCount As Long
    If IncludeZero Then
        If IsZeroOdd Then zCount = OddsCount Else zCount = EvensCount
    End If
    
    Dim iMod As Long: iMod = LastInteger Mod 2
    Dim eCount As Long: eCount = Int(LastInteger / 2)
    Dim oCount As Long: oCount = Int(LastInteger / 2) + iMod
    
    Dim dtCount As Long
    dtCount = eCount * EvensCount + oCount * OddsCount + zCount
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim dt As Long: dt = 1
    Dim n As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    If DoReturnRow Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To dtCount)
        If zCount > 0 Then
            For dt = 1 To zCount: Data(1, dt) = 0: Next dt
        End If
        For n = 1 To LastInteger
            For r = 1 To eoArr(n Mod 2)
                Data(1, dt) = n
                dt = dt + 1
            Next r
        Next n
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To dtCount, 1 To 1)
        If zCount > 0 Then
            For dt = 1 To zCount: Data(dt, 1) = 0: Next dt
        End If
        For n = 1 To LastInteger
            For r = 1 To eoArr(n Mod 2)
                Data(dt, 1) = n
                dt = dt + 1
            Next r
        Next n
    End If
    
    GetArrayOfIntegers = Data

End Function

' This is an unrelated example to play with.
' Note that changing the fourth parameter will make no difference since
' the results are written to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
Sub GetArrayOfIntegersTEST()
' Needs the 'GetArrayOfIntegers' function.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetArrayOfIntegers(4, 3, 2, False, False, False)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Debug.Print Data(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to ping this again, but what do I modify if the input cell is in sheet1 and the output cells are in sheet2?

Comment: Right before (above) `Dim dCell As Range` add the lines `Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")`. Right after (next to) it use the modified `Set dCell = dws.Range("B2"): dCell.Value = 0` (i.e. change `ws` to `dws`).

Answer (score 1):

**Fast alternative via ArrayList**

Working with an *ArrayList* *(disposing btw of methods like `.Sort`,`.Remove`, `.Insert`, `.Reverse`)* may be a convenient way to manipulate array data in a very readable way. It is not part of VBA, but can be accessed easily via late binding (referring to .Net library mscorlib.dll).

```
Option Explicit                          ' code module head

Sub DoubleEvenNumbersGreaterOne()
'a) define upper limit
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1                       ' << change to project's sheet Code(Name)
    Dim Limit As Long
    Limit = ws.Range("B1")
'b) declare ArrayList 
    Dim arr As Object                     ' late bind .Net mscorlib.dll
    Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")  
'c) populate list array
    arr.Add 0                             ' start adding with zero
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Limit                    ' loop through sequence 1:Limit
        arr.Add i                         ' add current number
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then arr.Add i     ' additional even number
    Next
'd) get array 
    Dim a As Variant: a = arr.ToArray     ' change ArrayList object to VBA array
    'Debug.Print Join(a, "|")             ' optional check in VB Editor's immediate window
'e) write 0-based 1-dim array to ws (here: Sheet1) or declare another target worksheet (e.g. ws2)
    With ws.Range("B2")
        .EntireRow = vbNullString        ' empty target row
        .Resize(1, UBound(a) + 1) = a    ' write values into correct number of cells
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**A formula oriented approach** // late edit as of 11/1 2021

a) A first and very elementary way would be to

- enter formula `=COLUMN(A1)-INT((COLUMN(A1)+2)/3)` into cell `B2` and to
- copy into the right neighbour cells as long as you get the wanted maximum

b) Refining this approach you can code the following udf accepting the wanted **maximum** as argument *(note that I changed the *flat* Column reference to a *vertical* Row reference to simplify calculation of the actual maxima)*:

```
Function Sequ(ByVal maxNo As Long)
    Dim myFormula As String
    myFormula = Replace("=ROW(1:$)-INT((ROW(1:$)+2)/3)", "$", maxNo + maxNo \ 2 + 1)
    Sequ = Application.Transpose(Evaluate(myFormula))
End Function
```

A direct formula entry of e.g. `=Sequ(10)` into `B2` benefitting from the newer dynamic features of vers. 2019+/MS 365 would display all (row) elements automatically in a so called spill range without need of further inputs.

Using **VBA** to display results in VB Editor's immediate window could be coded as follows: `Debug.Print Join(Sequ(10), "|")` resulting in

```
0|1|2|2|3|4|4|5|6|6|7|8|8|9|10|10
```

or to assign the results to a variable that can be used in further code.

Comment: As usual, you did not disappoint (I prefer `arl` though). Why the `ArrayList`? To write the values from a collection you need to loop. The dictionary Keys deal with unique values, while the Items could be interesting (you would need to increment another variable for the keys e.g. `dict(n) = i` and finish with `.Resize(1, dict.Count) = dict.Items`). Although an array has to be resized multiple times, it is questionable how less efficient it would be, if at all. But I think the number of elements is easily calculated before writing to a data structure, leaving the array the most efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim v, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, ii As Long, n As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    v = ws.Range("B1").Value
    If Not IsNumeric(v) Or IsEmpty(v) Then MsgBox "Must Be Number", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    ReDim a(1 To (v / 2) + v)
    For i = 1 To v
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            For ii = 1 To 2
                n = n + 1: a(n) = i
            Next ii
        Else
            n = n + 1: a(n) = i
        End If
    Next i
    Range("C2").Resize(, UBound(a)).Value = a
End Sub
```